# Bookmarklet to briefly flash a message

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, bookmarklet

Trying to develop a Bookmarklet to copy contents of a specific field on webpage AND then briefly flash a confirmation message. Already have both parts working separately. Can't figure out how to combine them to be able to then put that code into URL field of Bookmarklet.

```js
javascript: (function(){var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");copyText.select();document.execCommand("Copy"); 
function tempAlert(msg,duration)
{
     var el = document.createElement("div");
     el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:5%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
     el.innerHTML = msg;
     setTimeout(function(){
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     },duration);
     document.body.appendChild(el);
}

var d = document.getElementById('mergeFields-input-text');
d.onclick = function(){ tempAlert("Copied",5000); })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add the 'onclick' event. Try this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");

    tempAlert("Copied", 5000);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:5%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```

Comment: Splendid. BTW this is to compensate for the change DocuSign implemented, where when you send an envelope initially it populates the subject line with file's name (unique), but when you add template it replaces subject with template's subject (generic).   This Bookmarklet simplifies copying unique subject before adding a template.  I will need to adapt this to my paste Bookmarklet so it too will give a brief confirmation right under the Bookmarklet itself.

Comment: thanks!  Copying works.  I am trying to adopt your solution also to pasting for a separate Bookmarklet, everything else remains the same.  Here's what I have so far, but it does not work:

Comment: Trying to adopt your solution to pasting for a separate Bookmarklet, everything else remains the same. But it does not work: javascript:(function() {var pasteText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
.select();
document.execCommand("Paste");
tempAlert("PASTED SUBJECT", 500);
function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:2%;left:35%;background-color:green;");
el.innerHTML = msg;
document.body.appendChild(el);
setTimeout(function(){
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}, duration);}})();

Comment: The 'paste' command is disabled for web content. See details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

Comment: Following script works for pasting without a problem.  Only when I tried to adopt your solution above from copying to pasting, nothing is happening...  javascript: (function(){var pasteText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text").select();document.execCommand("paste"); })();

Comment: Following works for pasting - Thanks to @Shugar  javascript:(function() {var pasteText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text").select();
    document.execCommand("Paste");
 tempAlert("PASTED SUBJECT", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
 el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:2%;left:45%;background-color:yellow;");el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
 
        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();

Answer (score 0):

Above code from Shugar answers my question for copying, and this code below, also from him, does same except pasting:

```js
javascript:(function() {
    var pasteText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text").select();
    document.execCommand("Paste");
 
 
    tempAlert("PASTED SUBJECT", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:2%;left:45%;background-color:yellow;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
 
        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```